# Dynamodb SK range key is not returning data as expected

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using the below query to get from DB (GSI):

```
results = table.query(
        IndexName="Table-ID-index",
        KeyConditionExpression=Key("id").eq(id),
    )
```

However, my data is not sort based on the range key set with the GSI. Sample response I am getting with above query:

```
{
  "value": "test1",
  "sk": "1#1",
  "id": "1"
},
{
  "value": "test19",
  "sk": "19#19",
  "id": "19"
},
{
  "value": "test2",
  "sk": "2#2",
  "id": "2"
}
```

sk 19 should come after sk 2. Is there anything I have missed in my query?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, this is because the strings being stored and sorted in their UTF-8 encoded form. [From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html):

"DynamoDB collates and compares strings using the bytes of the underlying UTF-8 string encoding. For example, "a" (0x61) is greater than "A" (0x41), and "¿" (0xC2BF) is greater than "z" (0x7A)."